# Laravel paginate and merge

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

In my Laravel project, I get the data in the first 3 lines of my code and combine it and use it in my view page, but I use the full data ->get(); I paginate after shooting with . My aim is to pull data from 3 different categories with paginate in this function in the controller and equalize them to a single variable.

My Controller Function

```
    public function allApprovedQuestions(Request $request)
{
    $csQuestions = QuestionCheck::where('QUESTION_TYPE', 1)->with('questionsCS')->get();

    $daQuestions = QuestionCheck::where('QUESTION_TYPE', 2)->with('questionsDA')->get();

    $dyQuestions = QuestionCheck::where('QUESTION_TYPE', 3)->with('questionsDY')->get();

    $csCount = $csQuestions->count();
    $daCount = $daQuestions->count();
    $dyCount = $dyQuestions->count();

    $nonPagiinatedQuestions = collect();

    foreach ($csQuestions as $csQuestion) {
        $nonPagiinatedQuestions->push((object)[
            'id' => $csQuestion->questionsCS->SID,
            'question' => $csQuestion->questionsCS->SORU,
            'type' => $csQuestion->QUESTION_TYPE,
        ]);
    }

    foreach ($daQuestions as $daQuestion) {
        $nonPagiinatedQuestions->push((object)[
            'id' => $daQuestion->questionsDA->SID,
            'question' => $daQuestion->SORU1,
            'type' => $daQuestion->QUESTION_TYPE,
        ]);
    }

    foreach ($dyQuestions as $dyQuestion) {
        $nonPagiinatedQuestions->push((object)[
            'id' => $dyQuestion->questionsDY->SID,
            'question' => $dyQuestion->questionsDY->SORU,
            'type' => $dyQuestion->QUESTION_TYPE,
        ]);
    }

    $perPage = 2;
    $currentPage = request()->input('page', 1);
    $currentPageItems = $nonPagiinatedQuestions->slice(($currentPage - 1) * $perPage, $perPage)->all();
    $questions = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageItems, $nonPagiinatedQuestions->count(), $perPage, $currentPage);

    return view('content.approved-questions', compact('questions', 'csCount', 'daCount', 'dyCount'));
}
```

My View Code

```
                                            <tbody>
                                            @php
                                                $i = 1;
                                            @endphp

                                            @if($questions->isEmpty())
                                                <tr class=" text-center">
                                                    <td colspan="4">Soru Yok</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            @else
                                                @foreach ($questions as $question)
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            {{$i++}}
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            {{$question->question}},
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @if ($question->type == 1)
                                                                Çoktan Seçmeli
                                                            @elseif ($question->type == 2)
                                                                Doğru - Yanlış
                                                            @else
                                                                Boşluklu
                                                            @endif
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <form action="{{ route('spesificQuestion')}}" method="post">
                                                                @csrf
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{$question->id}}">
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="{{$question->type}}">
                                                                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                                                                    <i class="bi bi-eye"></i>
                                                                </button>
                                                            </form>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                @endforeach
                                            @endif
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                                            <ul class="pagination">
                                                {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
                                                <li class="page-item {{ $questions->onFirstPage() ? 'disabled' : '' }}">
                                                    <a class="page-link" href="{{ $questions->previousPageUrl() }}" aria-label="Previous">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo; Önceki</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>

                                                {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
                                                @for ($i = 1; $i <= $questions->lastPage(); $i++)
                                                    @if ($i == 1 || $i == $questions->lastPage() || ($i >= $questions->currentPage() - 2 && $i <= $questions->currentPage() + 2))
                                                        <li class="page-item {{ $questions->currentPage() == $i ? 'active' : '' }}">
                                                            <a class="page-link" href="/all-approved-questions{{ $questions->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    @elseif ($i == $questions->currentPage() - 3 || $i == $questions->currentPage() + 3)
                                                        <li class="page-item disabled">
                                                            <span class="page-link">...</span>
                                                        </li>
                                                    @endif
                                                @endfor

                                                {{-- Next Page Link --}}
                                                <li class="page-item {{ $questions->hasMorePages() ? '' : 'disabled' }}">
                                                    <a class="page-link" href="{{ $questions->nextPageUrl() }}" aria-label="Next">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">Sonraki &raquo;</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </nav>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#where-clauses) clause with an array of `with` statements and then paginate it.

```
$csQuestions = QuestionCheck::whereIn('QUESTION_TYPE', [1, 2, 3])->with([
    'questionsCS',
    'questionsDA',
    'questionsDY',
])->paginate();
```